Did I see the green flash, twice?
I was at the beach today at Costa Ballena in Spain. I was hunkered down to take a photo of the waves and the setting sun. Just as the last part of the sun was about to go below the horizon, I thought the last part of the disk turned green.
When I stood up, I saw it again.
Did I see the green flash, and did I see it twice? I am about 1.85m tall.
What I saw looked like this
This is the last photo that I took, which does not show any green:


How would we know what you saw?

It's perfectly reasonable to have been able to see it twice even stationary. The atmosphere/the Sun/the human body is a complicated system.

Some people say that you can stand on the beach and as soon as you see the green flash, if you sprint up the stairs to the top of the hotel (or sprint up the whatever to the top of wherever) you can see it again. Makes me wonder, what if we wrapped the hotel with a giant, white sheet; and what if we watched the sheet instead of watching the sun set. At some point, the upper part of the sheet still will be in reddish sunlight, and the bottom of the sheet will be in shadow. If the green flash is real, and if we take a photo, will it not capture a thin band of green separating the two?

P.S., Isn't that the Loch Ness Monster swimming toward the left edge of the picture, a bit below the horizon? I thought that the green flash was mostly a tropical thing.

A rough calculation (2m tall -> horizon 5km away, which is 1/8000 of Earth's circumference -> 1/8000 of 24 hours =10.8 seconds for visibility of green flash to rise 2 metres, or 5 seconds from crouching to standing - yes you may well have seen it twice. Or, of course, you may not have seen it at all.

@Ghoster Indeed, let's assume that because I am asking on Physics StackExchange and not Psychology StackExchange, that I am asking from a "is it physically possible to see it twice, by moving from crouching to standing" and not a "did I hallucinate or make it up"? What do you think? Sure, I could have phrased the question better, to make it clearer that I was asking about geometry.

@Peter Interesting - I always assumed that the horizon was 40 km away. I need to look into this. Thanks for the calculation, this is what I was wondering about.

I used the distance-to-horizon calculator at https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/distance-to-horizon

@Peter I confirmed your "5 seconds" comment the other day when I recorded a video of another cloud-free sunset. The two sunset instances were approximately 5 seconds apart, from crouching to standing. Please turn your comment into an answer, then I can accept it.

Recall what happens with a mirage: a substantial bending of the light trajectory. So this tells you that dynamic atmospheric conditions can easily bend the sun's light enough to make multiple green flashes.

It is quite possible that you saw the green flash again after standing up.
This distance-to-horizon calculator gives the distance to the horizon from a height of 2 metres as 5 kilometres.
Now 5km is roughly 1/8000 of the Earth's great equatorial circumference, and 1/8000 of 24 hours is 10.8 seconds. So it would take about 10 seconds for the Earth to turn far enough to lower the position of an observer's feet from the line of the green flash to 2m below the line of the green flash. Equivalently one could say that in this time the horizon moves 5km away and the height of the green flash's visibility rises from 0m to 2m.
This would be roughly 5 seconds from a crouching position to a standing position, and a reasonably able-bodied person could do this in about 2 seconds. So the answer is yes, you may well have seen the green flash while crouching and again after standing.

I recorded a video a few days later and, indeed, I measured about 5 seconds between the seeing the sunset while crouching and again when I stood up. I didn't see green, though, so those events are rarer.
